# Serialize kotlin data class in gradle's buildSrc/ during build

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm looking to produce json files during the build cycle of my kotlin gradle app.  My intent is to be able to instantiate data classes with a combination of public and private app configuration values that get put into the build's resources directory.

I'm looking at kotlinx.serialization, and I'd like to define these classes ideally in the projet's `buildSrc/`.

I haven't found any resources online for trying to setup serialization within gradle's build process, and not just configuring it for the app at runtime.  This is what I've put together as my `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.3.72"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.1.0")
}
```

And this is my test data class:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class JsonGenerator(val x: String = "")
```

The error I get is:

```
Cannot access 'Serializable': it is internal in 'kotlin.io'
```

It seems that this error can happen when the dependency isn't properly declared.  But I'm still unclear whether buildSrc has restrictions that make this impossible or not.  I'm not married to this approach, but this seemed like the best solution.

Edit:

I've changed my buildSrc/build.gradle.kts to:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("serialization"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.1")
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work, by doing: import kotlinx.serialization.*
I do not have the serialization plugin, in the plugins block but instead in dependencies: 

    implementation(kotlin("serialization"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.1")

my test class was top level in the buildSrc/main/kotlin folder, and I was able to properly access it in the parent build.gradle.kts

Comment: Moving my class to the root of the src directory worked.  Not sure why, but that did it.  If you make a proper answer out of this comment I'll mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure:

```
buildSrc
  main
   Kotlin
    MyTempClass.kt
```

It is important for the kt file to not be nested, I think that will only work if the file is the same name as the nesting directory

Inside of my data class file:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*

@Serializable
data class MyTempClass(val name: String)
```

I had a specific implementation of serialization, without the plugin.

Then in the top level build.gradle.kts, the MyTempClass was accessible